# Field 'id' expected a number but got.list value

Tags: python, django

I m trying to fetch session cart using key value but getting error like this:
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got ['3', '2', '4', '6', '8'].
"GET /book/cart/ HTTP/1.1" 500 134321

What I need to change:

`models.py`

```
class Book(models.Model):
    Books_cond_choice = (
        ('Old Book', 'Old'),
        ('New Book', 'New'),
    )

    book_id = models.AutoField
    book_condition = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Books_cond_choice)
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    book_auther = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    subcategory = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    pagecount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='book/images', default="")


    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_name

    @staticmethod
    def get_books_by_id(id):
        return int(Book.objects.filter(id__in = [id]))
```

`views.py`

```
class Cart(View):
    def get(self, request):
        ids = list(request.session.get('cart').keys())
        books = Book.get_books_by_id(ids)
        print(books)
        return render(request, 'book/cart.html', {'books' : books})
```

Comment: `ids` is already a list, yet you put it inside a list again...

Answer (score 0):

Your `list()` in the `Cart.get()` returns a list already, so you can just pass it to the filter as-is.
I'd suggest renaming it, so in the function you see that it is a list

```
def get_books_by_id(ids_list):
    return int(Book.objects.filter(id__in = ids_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line `ids = list(request.session.get('cart').keys())` I assume you get a list of ids of the `Book` instances. Later you use `Book.get_books_by_id(ids)` of which your implementation is as follows:

```
@staticmethod
    def get_books_by_id(id):
        return int(Book.objects.filter(id__in = [id]))
```

The problem is that `ids` is already a list. Also this should be a `classmethod` instead of a `staticmethod`. Also I believe you want the instances of the books instead of an integer (type casting to `int` does not make much sense anyway).

```
class Book(models.Model):
    Books_cond_choice = (
        ('Old Book', 'Old'),
        ('New Book', 'New'),
    )

    book_id = models.AutoField # Also this is not even used?? Why have it here?
    book_condition = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Books_cond_choice)
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    book_auther = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    subcategory = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    pagecount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='book/images', default="")


    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_name

    @classmethod
    def get_book_by_id(cls, id):
        try:
            return cls.objects.get(id=id)
        except cls.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    @classmethod
    def get_books_by_ids(cls, ids): # renamed function as it expected multiple ids
        return cls.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
```

Now your view:

```
class Cart(View):
    def get(self, request):
        ids = list(request.session.get('cart').keys())
        books = Book.get_books_by_ids(ids)
        print(books)
        return render(request, 'book/cart.html', {'books' : books})
```